# Calculating number of turns an electromagnet has

Tags: electromagnetism, coil, magnetics, electromagnetic, tesla-coil

The title, but can one calculate the amount of turns on a coil or find that out somehow? Because I purchased a 120m copper coil (originally intended on using it on another coil former before giving up as they broke)
Dimensions:
Copper length = 120m
Coil Height: 59.5mm
Coil Diameter: 56.5mm
Copper Coil Wire Diameter: 0.71mm

Comment: If you know the electrical resistance of the coil and what its AWG is.....

Comment: That will give the length (could also be done by weight).  That would only give an approximation of the number of turns.  But the OP tells is the length of wire anyway.

Comment: Ask whoever wound it.

Comment: In theory it may be possible to make a transformer - insert a proper closed magnetic loop core (=high permability iron which does NOT have a way for shorting eddy current), another known winding and see what's the voltage transformation ratio. This is useless if you do not know anything of practical design of working transformers..

Answer (score 1):

<strike>If the outer diameter is 60 mm, and the inner is (guessing) 20 mm, then the mean turn diameter is 40 mm, mean turn length is 126 mm, so number of turns will be 952.</strike>
As the outer diameter is 54 mm, and the inner is 20.5 mm, the mean turn diameter is 37.25, turn length  is 117 mm, so 1025 turns IF it's 120 m long, the data sheet doesn't mention length.

Let's try it another way. <strike>If the height is 60 mm, then the copper window is 60x20 = 1200 mm2 (using the same inner turn guess). With wire 0.71 mm diameter, that's a square area of about 0.5 mm2, giving 2400 as the upper limit on the number of turns,</strike>  If the height is 60 mm, then the copper window is 60*16.75 = 1005 mm2. With wire nominally 0.78 mm (extra for the enamel!), that's about 0.61 mm2 square area, giving 1650 turns as an upper limit, (as the wire will take up a bit more space if it's scramble wound,

<strike>To get either of those estimates more believable, and it would be nice if they were closer to each other, you need to measure the internal diameter of the coil, and the actual external diameter of the wire.</strike> With the new dimensions, the numbers are much closer to each other.

You do realise that is a reel of copper wire, and not a magnet?

Comment: Checked for the internal diameter (where the coil is being wound on) and found it to be 20.5mm. The external Diameter is exactly 54.00mm. As this is a copper wire with its insulation on (enamelled if you call it) its total wire diameter (both measured and stated on its website) is 0.71mm

Comment: I found more data on it here: https://docs.rs-online.com/c3d3/0900766b8157f397.pdf

Comment: Hey thanks for your response man, and yeah no I see that. Hindsight was 2020 and was more focused on trying to find the number of turns rather than its naming. Its purposes were still the same though, just to be used as an electromagnet.

Answer (score 0):

If we know the Inductance of a coil then we can calculate the number of turns....where L = {(N^2)uA}/l...where is L is the inductance of the coil and A is the cross section area and u is the relative permeability and l is the mean length

Comment: I was also considering that but that's the thing, how do I actually calculate the inductance of a coil? From what I've found from research, a multimeter isn't "fast" enough to determine its inductance(?)

Comment: Fast, do you mean accurate? you can take error approximations.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, but after reading the inductance using an inductance meter, I got 21.7mH, after that used the inductance equation and got 643 as number of turns, should be accurate.

Comment: Okay Good Job....Yeah It should be accurate!